# How to find angle between tangent on curve an Y axis

Tags: geometry

Lets say there is a curve whose curvature is given as k = 0.01. What i want to calculate is angle between tangent drawn at point "P" which is at a distance of "X" along the curve and Y axis (shown as θ in pic) . [image]

Can any relation be established among θ, X, and K or R(radius)?

Comment: If the curve is a circle which center is on the horizontal axis, then $x = R\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

The angle between a curve and the $X$-axis is the derivate of that curve, so if you know the equation of your curve, you try to write it as $y=f(x)$ and you calculate the derivate ($\frac{df}{dx}(x)$).

Comment: Consider curve as a part of circle whose radius is given. How to find θ form Y axis in original pic?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information, as the slope of the tangent line dictates the angle. The slope is not dependent on the curvature nor the position. You can move the point *P* around and it will move the center of curvature to keep the radius $R$ as specified.

If you can find the slope of the tangent line $m$, then $$\theta = \tfrac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}( m) $$

Please note that there might be an inherent assumption in the question that the center of curvature lies on the horizontal axis somewhere. There is never a mathematical reason for this to occur in general, other than for a *specific* problem for which this is prescribed.